# Page layout of custom settings

Tags: page-layout, customsetting

Can we change the page layout of custom settings' fields (under manage) like we have in various object's record pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't Edit the Page layout for custom setting.

There is one idea which you can vote

[Page Layouts for Custom Settings](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HIrQ)

Answer (score 1):

No!  Here's the idea to upvote

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HIrQAAW